# Python converting time from string to timedelta to find time difference

Tags: python, dataframe, timedelta

how do I convert string to timedelta in order to create a new column within my dataframe?

```
from  pandas as pd
from numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

pricetime = pd.DataFrame({'price1':[22.34, 44.68, 52.98], 'time1':['9:48:14', '15:54:33', '13:13:22'],'price2':[28.88, 47.68, 22.32], 'time2':['10:52:44', '15:59:59', '10:12:22']})

pricetime['price_change'] = np.where(pricetime['time1'] < pricetime['time2'], (pricetime['price1'] - pricetime['price2'])/pricetime['price2'], np.nan)
pricetime['time_diff'] = np.where(pricetime['time1'] < pricetime['time2'], pricetime['time2'] - pricetime['time1'], np.nan)
```

When I do this. I get an error for the time where I'm subtracting the two different times.

I tried to do this but it gave me an error:

```
pricetime['price_change'] = np.where((datetime.strptime(pricetime['time1'], '%H:%M:%S') < datetime.strptime(pricetime['time2'], '%H:%M:%S')), (pricetime['price1'] - pricetime['price2'])/pricetime['price2'], np.nan)
pricetime['time_diff'] = np.where((datetime.strptime(pricetime['time1'], '%H:%M:%S') < datetime.strptime(pricetime['time2'], '%H:%M:%S'), datetime.strptime(pricetime['time2'], '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(pricetime['time1'], '%H:%M:%S'), np.nan)
```

The error it gave is:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

Comment: datetime.strptime work on one string no a pandas series. You need to either use list comprehension or pd.apply to convert the series from strings to datetimes.

Comment: what is your final goal? what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Just a difference in time between time1 and time2. So for the first row time1 = 9:48:14 and time2 = 10:52:44. I want a new column to give me the difference between the two time. 1:04:30

Comment: And also anything time related. If time2 > time1 then I want the difference between the prices and put it in as a new column.

Comment: use `pd.to_datetime(pricetime['time1'])` to get the times. 
so time diffs are: `pd.to_datetime(pricetime['time1']) - pd.to_datetime(pricetime['time2'])`   if you can provide an example of an output I could write a function...

Comment: pricetime['time_diff'] = np.where(pd.to_datetime(pricetime['time1']) < pd.to_datetime(pricetime['time2']), pd.to_datetime(pricetime['time2']) - pd.to_datetime(pricetime['time1']), np.nan)

Comment: So I did it this way but now I'm getting an output that says:
TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[float16]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[timedelta64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246446/discussion-between-aking-and-marc-law).

Answer (score 2):

after a discussion with @Marc_Law the answer he looked for is:

```
pricetime['time_diff'] = pd.to_datetime(pricetime['time2']) - pd.to_datetime(pricetime['time1'])
pricetime.loc[pd.to_datetime(pricetime['time1']) >= pd.to_datetime(pricetime['time2']),'time_diff'] = np.nan
pricetime['time_diff'] = pricetime['time_diff'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(' ')[-1:][0])
```

what he needed is to have the difference only if the value in `time1` column was smaller than the value in `time2` column, otherwise put np.nan. than return it to string without the "X days".

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to find the difference in time, then you can follow this sample

```
from datetime import datetime


foo = '9:48:14'
bar = '15:54:33'

foo = datetime.strptime(foo, '%H:%M:%S')
bar = datetime.strptime(bar, '%H:%M:%S')

print(bar - foo)
```

**Output**

```
6:06:19
```

Further [reading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Comment: I tried to do that but it gave me an error. Do you know what I did wrong? I'm still new to Python.

Comment: @Marc_Law You are passing a whole column, you need to iterate over the rows and pass each of them when comparing

Comment: `pd.to_datetime()` is more suitable for this question.